# Generic method for multiple db tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have multiple tables with the same structure and want to write a generic function that return data from the correct table.

Now:

```
var a = context.TableA.Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault.Name;
var b = context.TableB.Where(b => b.id == id).FirstOrDefault.Name;
```

I want something like this:

```
var a = GetName<TableA>(id);
var b = GetName<TableB>(id);

GetName<T>(int id){
 //right table
 return context<T>.Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefault.Name;
}
```

But I can't get the context to get the right table with generic T.

Comment: FYI you can shorten it to `context.TableA.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id == id).Name` but note that leaves you open to a null reference exception if `FirstOrDefault` returns `null`.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't be better off with using projections and interfaces? Assuming you have some place where you are going to use the different type of objects with the Name property sounds like an interface would be a better way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this without getting `context`, so, you can add another class, pass context to it as argument of constructor, save it to private field and define `GetName` method inside. Like this:

```
public class EntityHelper
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    public EntityHelper(DbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public string GetName<T>(int id)
    {
        return this._context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefault().Name;
    }
}
```

for method `GetName` there should be constraint, because compiler don't know does `T` has property called `Name`

also I recommend you to change `FirstOrDefault()` to `First()`, because if you will access property of `FirstOrDefault()` result, when it's return `null` - you'll get `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Using First() will cause an exception as well if nothing matched the Where()... So better use FirstOrDefault and check for null before getting the Name.

Comment: I get this error message: The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set<TEntity>()'

Comment: add constraint `public string GetName<T>(int id) where T : class`

Comment: Should also explain how to add a constraint to ensure `T` has both a `Name` and `id` property.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen you are right. if this project will be rather big and you'll get `NullReferenceException` on this line - you can not be sure that it's because of `FirstOrDefault` - it can be also _context and result of Set. So if you'll use `First()` and get `InvalidOperationException` - you can be sure that it because of `First()`

Comment: @juharr all your entities should implement common interface (or inherit common abstract class) that define property Name, so you can add constraint `public string GetName<T>(int id) where T : yourInterfaceName`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
context.Set(typeof(T)).Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault.Name;
```

Where T should have restriction on having ID.

Comment: until context.Set(typeof(T)) is ok, but I don't have any Where function afterwards

Comment: You should have restriction on T, like where T : IEntity, that's having Id. And then cast context.Set(typeof(T)) to (IQueryable<T>). But in your case it's easier just to use find instead of where: return context.Set(typeof(T)).Find("a123");

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following helper (no changes to your classes is needed)

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static string GetName<T>(this DbContext db, int id)
        where T : class
    {
        var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "source");
        var idFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(source, "id"), Expression.Constant(id)),
            source);
        var nameSelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(
            Expression.Property(source, "Name"),
            source);
        return db.Set<T>().Where(idFilter).Select(nameSelector).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

like this

```
var a = context.GetName<TableA>(id);
var b = context.GetName<TableB>(id);
```